# When does a route's model get set in its controller?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to do some work in the init() of my controller with the data from the model in my route, but finding that it's not there yet.  I'm not sure if this is a runloop thing or if I'm just missing something completely.  Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/4909/edit) and the code, where the template can access the model but the controller can't from init():

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    {{firstName}} {{lastName}}</script>

App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

  init: function(){console.log(this.get('content'));}

  });


App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
      return {firstName: 'Kris', lastName: 'Selden'};
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens during the default implementation of `setupController`, which happens after the controller has been created and initialized.  It looks a little like this (here I'm overriding it and doing what it would normally do)

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
      return {firstName: 'Kris', lastName: 'Selden'};
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    controller.set('model', model);
  }
});
```